# CoffeeScript --bare function changed?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

The parameter `--bare` in CoffeeScript has been changed. Does anyone know what new parameter does the same function?

Comment: Can you give more info? What is --bare?

Comment: You should pick an answer to your question by selecting the green checkbox near the answer that answers your question best

Answer (score 4):

By default, when coffee-script compiles a file, it wraps the result using a "self-invoking anonymous function" like so:

```
(function() {
  // compiled code here...
}).call(this);
```

You can find more reference about this here: http://2007-2010.lovemikeg.com/2008/08/17/a-week-in-javascript-patterns-self-invocation/

The *--bare* flags prevent this wrapping from happening.

Comment: Man, the new code to compile is "coffee --compile --no-wrap" before was "coffee --compile --bare", but tks for help-me.